# Concurrency exception trying to update SQL from datagridview grouped rows

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview, dataset, tableadapter

In my scenario I use Visual Studio and I have a datagridview filled by a query stored in a `TableAdapter` like this:

```
SELECT pn_produttore
FROM partlist_RMA
WHERE Id_RMA = @Id_RMA
GROUP BY pn_produttore
```

I fill the results in the datagridview with this function:

```
this.partlist_RMATableAdapter.FillByID_RMAGrouped(this.pLMDataSet.partlist_RMA, 6124);
```

but when the `CellEndEdit` event runs and it was called this function:

```
Validate();
partlistRMABindingSource.EndEdit();
partlist_RMATableAdapter.Update(pLMDataSet.partlist_RMA);
```

I get a concurrency exception.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171936.aspx

Comment: I think the problem is that the data is grouped. But i don't know how to solve. I need to update more rows in the database editing a single row in datagridview.

Comment: can you show the update statement\s?

Comment: Thinking you will need to pull all the records as a datatable then just display the grouped data in your grid. When you update iterate through each record and only update the data if it is actually different, catching the exceptions as you go , and deal with them separately. Assuming locking the table is out of the question.